# Can I use Pantheon-Files FileChooserDialog module from custom FileChooserDialog Object?

Tags: programming, development, vala

I want to use the new Pantheon-Files FileChooserDialog module, but it doesn't seem to work when creating my own widget based on Gtk.FileChooserDialog (like seen below). Is there anyway for me to be able to do this?

```
namespace App.Dialogs {

    public class FileDialog : Gtk.FileChooserDialog {
        public FileDialog (string title, Gtk.Window? parent, Gtk.FileChooserAction action) {
             ...
             this.show_all ();
        }
    }
}
```